# NProgress.js to show progress of page loading

Tags: jquery, pageload

I am trying to figure out how to use NProgress.js as a generic page load for all pages on a site. I am unable to find any documentation or an easy way to add this loading effect on page load and have it finish when the entire page has loaded.

http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 26):

Simply put, place this JavaScript anywhere in your html, it's a good practice to place it before the closing body tag:

```
<script>

    // Show the progress bar 
    NProgress.start();

    // Increase randomly
    var interval = setInterval(function() { NProgress.inc(); }, 1000);        

    // Trigger finish when page fully loaded
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        NProgress.done();
    });

    // Trigger bar when exiting the page
    jQuery(window).unload(function () {
        NProgress.start();
    });

</script>
```

Oh and don't be confused, NProgress is in the global scope, it has nothing to do with jQuery, I'm using jQuery's `.load()`/`.unload()` for convenience only, and please don't put the `NProgress.start()` inside a jquery document's `.ready()`, it's useless clutter.

Answer (score 4):

In the main page: http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

I found this (with show page source code):

```
<script>
$('body').show();
$('.version').text(NProgress.version);
NProgress.start();
setTimeout(function() { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); }, 1000);

$("#b-0").click(function() { NProgress.start(); });
$("#b-40").click(function() { NProgress.set(0.4); });
$("#b-inc").click(function() { NProgress.inc(); });
$("#b-100").click(function() { NProgress.done(); });
</script>
```

As you can see, you need to use NProgress.start(); to starts de progress bar. Try something like this (i used jquery ready function):

```
<script>
NProgress.start();
NProgress.set(0.4);
//Increment 
var interval = setInterval(function() { NProgress.inc(); }, 1000);
$(document).ready(function(){
    NProgress.done();
    clearInterval(interval);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Will this show the loading and progress until entire page has loaded?

Comment: When the document is ready I call 'done()', so this will force the finish. But I don't know if this will work with images.

Comment: This solution is the best way to do it if you have some lazy load or scroll load. You set a time out independent of the page loading

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something with nprogress and came across your question. I am also using a scrollbar plugin and this is what I came up with:

```
<script>
    (function($) {

        NProgress.start();
        $("#user-book-list").hide();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(window).load(function() {

                $("#user-book-list").show();

                $("#user-book-list").mCustomScrollbar({
                    autoHideScrollbar: false,
                    horizontalScroll: true,
                    theme: "dark-thin",
                    advanced: { autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true, updateOnContentResize: false }
                });

                NProgress.done();

            });
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I'm sure you can just take out the custom scrollbar stuff and it'll achieve the desired result. I am sizing the `li`s in the `#user-book-list` `ul` and as a result, see a quick flash of unstyled elements. nprogress helped hide this, but now the images just pop in. A `fadeIn()` effect or something like that will ease that issue...lol.

EDIT: HubSpot's been cranking out some good open-source projects. One of which is a loader, inspired by nprogress, but is much easier to implement: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome

I am now using this instead of nprogress. No dependencies requires as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        NProgress.configure({
            showSpinner: false
        });
        NProgress.start();
</script>
```

Add above script under the body tag
And open bellow my GitHub repository link you will get the script add it to your page

https://github.com/mateentechbits/showSpinner_js_scripts/blob/main/nprogress.js